# How do I exclude the "click here" from mail header on the generated web page?

Tags: civimail

Mail sends out with a header that contains **click here to view online** and links to http://www.example.com/civicrm/mailing/view?reset=1&id=77

Within their email client, the link takes them to the appropriate page, however that page includes **click here to view online** which links to http://www.example.com/civicrm/mailing/%22http://www.example.com/civicrm/mailing/view?reset=1&id=77%22.

This incorrect links takes them to a CiviMail search page.

Preferably, I'd like to hide the header and the footer from the generated web page rather than correct the url, but I'd be happy either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping those items in `<span class="hiddenElement"> </span>`. Civi's css will hide it on your website, but email clients will not.